# Subset data frame using dplyr with a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I know how to use dplyr but here I'm stuck

I have a vector such as :

```
v <- c("A","B","C")
```

and a dataframe such as

```
Groups letters 
G1 A
G1 B
G1 C
G1 C
G2 A
G2 C
G3 A
G3 A
G3 C
G4 C
```

And I would like ton only keep `Groups` that have all the `letters`.

and then keep only G1 in this exemple because all `A,B` and `C` present in `v` are present.

I tried:

```
filtred_df2=filtred_df %>%
  group_by(Groups) %>%
  filter(all(letters %in% v))
```

Comment: @hmhensen no I still get the same data frame

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood your question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `v %in% letters`? At least that keeps 'G1'

Comment: Another use case for `setequal` - `dat %>% group_by(Groups) %>% filter(setequal(letters,v))`

Comment: Yes it works I put v at the first position thank you

Comment: And what if I want to be less stringent and authorize to have only 2 sequences instead of the 3 ? @thelatemail

Comment: @chippycentra - set operations still have you covered - `intersect` in this case - `dat %>% group_by(Groups) %>% filter(length(intersect(v, letters)) == 2)`

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a shorter way, but this should work. First, we limit the data to rows in V, then we count how many of the letters that group has and compare that to the number of unique letters in V. Finally join to original data to only include groups with all letters.

```
filtred_df %>%
  filter(letters %in% v) %>%  # Only care about letters that are in V
  count(Groups, letters) %>%   # or distinct(Groups, letters) %>%
  count(Groups) %>%
  filter(n == length(unique(v))) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  left_join(filtred_df)
```